# Points don't show up on the map after importing CSV file in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, point, csv, import

In QGIS 3.16.12 I have previously inserted survey location points by adding a delimited text layer (clicking the correct buttons and setting x and y as long and lat).

Though now, when uploading the same CSV file, using the same methods, the file appears to have a different geometry to that of a point file (points don't show on the map, I cannot change symbology or zoom to layer, etc).

All the field types also seem to be `Qstring` (where normally, QGIS detects my different field types). I have attached a screenshot below.

[image]

I believe I've done everything as I normally would, but the CSV file is not showing up with the points on the map. As it has worked for me before, could this be a problem with QGIS, or am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: please show us an example of your points - most likely error is that the projection is wrong

Comment: @IanTurton, thank you for your reply :) I have attached an image of my points, I am still experiencing the same problem and am not sure why. I have even updated my version of QGIS.

Comment: What CRS are you wanting to use? 27700 or 4326? Have you tried adding the XY as Easting Northing?

Comment: (With geometry CRS set to 27700 in the Points from Delimited text tool )

Comment: Hi @JoeBe, thanks so much for your reply :) My project CRS is 27700, though no matter what CRS I assign to the geometry, I still get the same result. I have also tried adding the XY to Easting Northing, though the points still show up un-editable with the list symbol next to them. Could this be a problem with my GIS programme?

Comment: Hello @Babel, the DMS coordinates did it! I didn't even realise that the box was checked, thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have lat/lon values, stick to CRS `EPSG:4326`. However, uncheck `DMS coordinates` box and make sure `X-field` (`Long`) and `Y-field` (`Lat`) are set to the right column name.